# How can I target a div inside an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

I have an element inside an `<iframe>` I'd like to activate using a link outside the `<iframe>`.

Example:

```
<iframe src="iframe.html" id="iframe">
    *inside the iframe*  
    <div id="activate" class="activate">
</iframe>
<a href="#activate" target="iframe">Link</a>
```

I thought this would work but obviously does nothing because I'm stupid. Any ideas?

Comment: If the frame is at the same domain, you can use: `var link_inside_iframe = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.getElementById("activate");`

Comment: @RobW why didn't you put that in as an answer?  Can you just go directly to the div? `var link_inside_iframe = document.getElementById("activat‌​e");` or do you have to go through the iframe to get to the div?

Comment: @norlando `document` in your code refers to the current document, ie the parent of the iframe. The `document` at my previous comment is pointing to the frames document. To "activate" (scroll to) the element, use `document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.getElementById("activat‌​e").scrollIntoView();` *answer, mmm*

Comment: @RobW Thanks for the answer, can you post an example of how I can use that line of code in an HTML page while attaching it to a link?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Framed page (`test.html`):

```
....... lots of content .... 
<div id="activate">Inside frame</div>
```

Page containing the frame (`page-containing-frame.html`):

```
<iframe src="test.html" name="target-iframe"></iframe>
<a href="test.html#activate"
       target="target-iframe"
       onclick="frames['target-iframe'].document.getElementById('activate')
                .scrollIntoView();return false">Click</a>
^ That's the link. I've split up code over multiple lines for visibility
```

### Explanation

- The frame has a **`name` attrbute** with the value of `target-iframe` (obviously, you can choose any desired value).
- The link contains three attributes, each supporting two methods to scroll to a link in the frame:

  1. `target="target-iframe"` and `href="test.html#activate"`
     This is the fallback method, in case of an error occurs, or if the user has disabled JavaScript.
     The target of the link is the frame, the **`href`** attribute **must** be the path of the frame, postfixed by the anchor, eg `test.hrml#activate`. This method will cause the framed page to **reload**. Also, if the anchor is already at `#activate`, this method will not work any more.
  2. This is the elegant solution, which shold not fail. The desired frame is accessed through the global `frames` object (by name, NOT by id, `target-iframe`). Then, the anchor is selected (`document.getElementById('activate')`.
     Finally, the  [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) method is used to move the element inside the viewport.
     The `onclick` method ends with `return false`, so that the default behaviour (ie following the link, causing a page refresh), does not happen.

Your current code did not work, because of the missing `name` attribute ([`target="..."`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) cannot match IDs, only names). Also, `#activate` is parsed in the context of the current page, so, the link points to `page-containing-frame.html`.